# Отправка пользователю сообщения посредством MSG вызваным из JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Имеется следующий JAVA код созданый и скомпилированый в БД Oracle.

```
create or replace and compile java source named windowserrors as
public class OpenWindows 
{
  public static void ErrorText() 
  {
       try
       {
         Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Msg * ошибка");
         while (true)
          {
           try 
           {
               proc.waitFor();
               break;
           } 
           catch (Exception t)
           {
               t.getMessage();
           }
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.getMessage();
       }
  }
}
```

Этот код должен запускать рассылку сообщений (для примера всем пользователям), о том, что совершена ошибка.
Написана простая процедура, которая должна его запускать на выполнение, а так же, собственно, сам вызов процедуры.

```
PROCEDURE Rise_error AS LANGUAGE JAVA  
NAME 'OpenWindows.ErrorText()';       

BEGIN
   p_oms_patreg.Rise_error;
END;
```

Но, при вызове процедуры ORACLE отрабатывает, но не выводится окно с сообщением. Хотя если запустить данный код на исполнение, например, в Eclipse - появляется соответствующее окно.

Перерыв достаточно много информации, так и не нашел подобный вариант реализации.

Comment: Возможно, глупый вопрос, но все-таки спрошу: Вы проверяете наличие сообщений на машине на которой находится сервер БД?

Comment: Я работаю через RDP на сервере где находится БД.
Если данную команду ввести в тот же CMD на RDP то сообщение же появится и у меня и у других пользователей.
Или я чего то не понимаю?
Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Просто уточнил, спасибо. Даже не знаю чем помочь. Что получится если убрать из Java-кода весь перехват исключений и объявить метод как `public static void ErrorText() throws Exception ...` ?

Comment: Пробовал - результат тот же. Тут дело, наверное, в взаимодействии java source и oracle pl/sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил, код выполняется нормально.

Убрал проглатывание ошибок:

```
create or replace and compile java source named windowserrors as
public class OpenWindows {
    public static void ErrorText() throws Exception {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Msg * ошибка");
        proc.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Создал процедуру:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Rise_error AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'OpenWindows.ErrorText()';
```

Вызвал ее:

```
begin
    rise_error();
end;
```

Первый раз, вылезло `ORA-29532` с сообщением о нехватке привилегий. Выдал привилегии, создал новое подключение к БД и выполнил заново. На сервере БД появилось сообщение (из-за кодировки поехала кириллица, но это уже другой вопрос).

Убедитесь, что:

- отключен перехват ошибок в Java (смотрите код выше);
- выполняется именно нужная процедура (нет ли здесь путаницы: `p_oms_patreg.Rise_error;`);
- наличие сообщений проверяется на сервере БД, на котором выполняется код.

Comment: Именно данный вариант подошел.
Только замену try/catch механизма на throws Exception, что по сути и решило проблему отображения и работы в целом - немного не понял. 
Пойду курну документацию.

И да в результате он ругнулся на права, выдал и всё ок. Хотя до этого вообще по сути не обрабатывал.

Спасибо!

Comment: @GordeySkr Пожалуйста! Проблема в том, что в `try/catch` код ничего не делал, из-за этого все ошибки перехватывались и игнорировались.

Answer (score 3):

Процедура отработала скорее всего с ошибкой. Но все исключения в коде отловлены, и что совсем плохо, сообщения о возможных ошибках не переданы в вызывающую программу. Функция `getMessage()` не выводит сообщение об ошибке.

Я бы сделал так:

```
create or replace and compile java source named Host as
public class Notifier 
{
    public static void notifyUsers (String message) {
        try {
            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder ("MSG", "*", message).start ();
            proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("The Users were notified via message=" + message);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("Exception: " + e.getMessage ()); // or e.printStackTrace
        }
    }
};
/ 
Java source HOST compiled

create or replace procedure notifyUsers (message varchar2) as 
language java name 'Notifier.notifyUsers (java.lang.String)';
/
Procedure NOTIFYUSERS compiled

set serveroutput on size unlimited
exec dbms_java.set_output(10000)

exec notifyUsers ('Unknown Error occurred')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Процедура вроде завершилась нормально, но на выводе сообщение об ошибке, что не хватает привилегий:

> Exception: the Permission (java.io.FilePermission <> execute)
>       has not been granted to SH. The PL/SQL to grant this is
>       dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SH', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '<>', 'execute' )

Под пользователем SYS надо дать недостающие привилегии. Имя схемы, в примере SH, надо заменить на реальное:

```
begin
    dbms_java.grant_permission('SH', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '<<ALL FILES>>', 'execute');
    dbms_java.grant_permission('SH', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission','writeFileDescriptor','*');
    dbms_java.grant_permission('SH', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission','readFileDescriptor','*');
end;
/
```

Теперь в новой сессии:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
exec dbms_java.set_output(10000)

exec notifyUsers ('Unknown Error occurred')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

The Users were notified via message=Unknown Error occurred
```

Comment: Так же рабочий вариант, даже сверх того, что было нужно (вывод сообщения на экран) 
А так же еще более подробно!)
Спасибо!

Comment: "даже сверх того, что было нужно" - как раз наоборот, сократил  готовое решение до самого минимума подогнав под задачу в вопросе. Цель была показать, что  у вас с try/catch не так. Но судя по комментариям получилось не очень доходчиво.

Comment: В данный момент уже разобрался. Спасибо.