# Oracle. Взаимодействие java_source, сессии oracle, windows MSG

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sendmessage

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо решить задачу отправки сообщения через стандартную утилиту Windows MSG. Вывод сообщения запускается в произвольном месте кода (проверки) при действии пользователя в приложении.

Имеется java_source в Oracle следующего содержания:

```
create or replace and compile java source named windowserrors as
public class OpenWindows {
    public static void ErrorText(String message,String sessia) throws Exception
    {
        /*Вызываем окно с ошибкой используя полученные параметры*/
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("msg "+ sessia +" "+ message);
        proc.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Его процедура вызов на Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Rise_error(message VARCHAR2,sessia VARCHAR2) AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'OpenWindows.ErrorText(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)';
```

И само обращение из Oracle SQL кода:
  begin
    rise_error('ошибка',sessia); 
  end;
Сессию получаю:

```
   SELECT replace(osuser,terminal||'\')
     INTO l_system_user
     from v$session c
    where username = USER
      AND status = 'ACTIVE'
      AND c.AUDSID = sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID');
```

Все порты, параметры работы отправки сообщений MSG настроены. Но при вызове кода на машинах пользователей, им не выводиться сообщение. Хотя параметр сессии получается на машинах верный.

Если запустить MSG из командной строки на машине пользователя с параметром сессии полученной в SQL коде, то сообщение выводиться на экран - то есть всё отрабатывает, но только при прямом вызове.
При этом на сервере всё отрабатывает именно при запуске из SQL.

Вопрос: что необходимо подкорректировать в сетевых параметрах/oracle параметрах и т.д. чтобы пользователи получали сообщения?
И возможна ли такая реализация в принципе?

Спасибо за помощь!

P.S: добавлять вывод сообщения на уровень приложения не можем, так как разработчики занятые люди.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, но при чем тут `javascript`?

Comment: ошибочно выставил. убрал

Comment: Посмотрите, возможно связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768349/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-msg-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-java)

Comment: Это моя же задача. И она никак не отвечает на вопрос данной.

Comment: Я вижу только разницу - там было всем пользователлям, а в этом вопросе только одному пользователю. А из коммандной строки работает?

Comment: Да, как и написал. Если открыть на машинах пользователей CMD и выполнить команду - сообщение появляется, что логично, ибо MSG настроен

Comment: Добавляйте имя так @имя, иначе не будет оповещения о новом сообщении, т.е. на деревню дедушке.

Comment: "Если открыть на машинах пользователей CMD", а если на машине, где установлена БД?

Comment: На машине где БД: так же работает MSG, работает и отправка сообщения из SQL кода

@имя - не входит в синтаксис команды MSG.

Comment: Я могу отправить сообщение с компьютера пользователя из SQL кода, то есть ORACLE на сервер  (где стоит БД) и оно там появится, а вот если наоборот - нет, в этом и проблема

Comment: "@имя - не входит в синтаксис команды MSG" - вы не поняли, **на этом ресурсе**  так надо в комментарии указывать, не в MSG.

Comment: Извините, повторюсь. Если вы на машине А, где установлена БД, в коммандной строке наберёте - `msg petya hi`, получает ли пользователь Петя на машине Б сообщение "hi"?

Comment: Извините, теперь буду знать.

Нет, в таком виде не получается. Но если `msg * hi` - все получают. Включая `petya`
Сейчас продолжаю курить мануалы по MSG:(